# implicit grant type with django oauth-toolkit

Tags: django, authentication, oauth

After reading about authentication flows for different clients, the suggested grant type for single-page application should be implicit.

However, there is no good documentation for using implicit grant types in Django OAuth-toolkit.

Here is how thought it works:
1. register the client as public, authorization grant type implicit and specify a redirect uri
2. 'curl -X POST -d "grant_type:implicit&username:&password:" -u "" http://localhost:8000/o/token/'
3. recieve the access token at the redirect uri

Maybe someone could clearify how implicit grant types should be handled.